# Limit of $1/k$ and the $p$-series test

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

When taking the limit of something, for example:

$$\lim\frac{1}{k+1}$$

as $k$ goes to infinity I was taught to multiply by $\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\frac{1}{k}}$ to get

$$\lim\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}$$

where I was told to assume that $\frac{1}{k}$ goes to $0$ and I end up with

$$\frac{0}{1} = 0.$$

However, I'm confused as by the $p$-series test $\lim\frac{1}{k}$ is divergent as $p$ must be greater than $1$. But shouldn't $\frac{1}{k}$ be $0$ and therefore converge to $0$?

(All limits going to infinity)

Comment: careful: $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1/k}{1+1/k}=\frac01=0$ but the expression $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac01$ is not correct, you are taking limits twice.

Comment: Sorry, that $lim\frac{0}{1}$ shouldn't have had the $lim$ there. I'm confused as to why when I take $lim\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}$ that $\frac{1}{k}$ becomes $0$ but not when I take the limit of just $\frac{1}{k}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the distinction between the limit of the summand and the limit of the partial sums. I recently wrote up a big post on this for my sister here: [Infinite amount of additions, finite sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489871/infinite-amount-of-additions-finite-sum/2524216#2524216)

Let $$s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

$ \\ $ By definition,

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$$

Although $1/k \to 0$, $s_n \to \infty$

Comment: I think you're right. I had been writing $lim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$ the same as just $lim\frac{1}{k}$ and never made a distinction between the two. Thank you.

Comment: @drewdawg7 If you read that link, I went into a lot more detail on series in general, and it may help clarify.

Comment: @Masacroso fixed. Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

The $p$-series test applies to a *series*: an infinite sum. It tells you that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$ is divergent. It says nothing about the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac1k$.